# Date-Formatting in TEXT formula independent from used language in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
           A                 B                          
1      2020-01-01        2020-01-01     =TEXT(A1,"YYYY-MM-DD")
2
3
```

In my spreadsheet I have a `date` written in `Cell A1` and change it to a `TEXT` format with the formula in `Cell B1`. 
All this works fine as long as I use the English version of Excel.

---

Now, a coworker in Poland needs to use the file in a polish Excel version. 
Once he opens the file the formula in `Cell B1` changes to:

```
=TEKST(A2;"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

This formula gives back an `error` because in Poland instead of `YYYY-MM-DD` you need to use `RRRR-MM-DD`. 
Therefore, I am wondering if it is somehow possible to make this **text formatting international** so no matter in which language your Excel is set up the formula is working?

Comment: You may be able to use a User Defined Function in VBA that you can call as a formula.  VBA is EN-US centric so language should not matter.

Comment: You are going to need VBA for this.  You should be able to apply this solution: [Date format excel in diferent systems German to English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64854470/date-format-excel-in-diferent-systems-german-to-english). You use VBA to create an appropriate Name for the date format code on Workbook open; then use that Name in your worksheet formula.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the only problem is sharing it with your Polish co-worker, then you can simply use the international placeholder "e" to replace "YYYY":

```
=TEXT(A1,"e-MM-DD")
```

Now, while this would work fine for your co-worker in Poland, there are countries where "m" and "d" would also need replacement. If in general we need to return the locale "Y", "M"  or "D" equivalent you could create three named formulas using the [name manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4):

- 1st: Create name called YT and refer to `=INDEX(GET.WORKSPACE(37),19)`
- 2nd: Create name called MT and refer to `=INDEX(GET.WORKSPACE(37),20)`
- 3rd: Create name called DT and refer to `=INDEX(GET.WORKSPACE(37),21)`

Now you can use a reference to these names through:

```
=TEXT(A1,REPT(YT,4)&"-"&REPT(MT,2)&"-"&REPT(DT,2))
```

---

**NOTE:** Depending on which version of Excel you use it could be necessary to: 
`Enable Excel 4.0 macros when VBA macros are enabled` in the `Trust Center`

Comment: Do you have a reference for that international placeholder?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I read about it first over [here](https://excel.tips.net/T003299_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html). Scroll down to the bottom and there is a mentioning about it. I'm struggling to find MS-documentation though.

Comment: I, too, have only seen it mentioned here and there, and I, too, have not been able to find any MS documentation.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, yes. Even searching for a good hour returns no hits. Yet it worked for me switching between English <> Dutch.Though I did come across an interesting idea to use `GET.WORKSPACE()`

Comment: My answer to the question I cited in the comments also creates a Name'd custom format code, but does it using VBA and the WorkbookOpen Event.

Comment: I added everything as you mentioned to the name manager but I get #NAME? as an error when I put the formula in your answer. I assume the issue is caused by the GET.WORKSPACE. My Excel is in German and there is no equivalent translation for this part into German.

Comment: @Michi, the german translation of that function is `=ARBEITSBEREICH.ZUORDNEN()`

Comment: Thanks. Now it works on my German computer. I cannot test it at the Polish vesion at the moment. I will let you know once I tried it and if it works.

Comment: Just checked it on the Polish version. Everything works. Nice solution and great explanation in the answer.

Comment: Here is good information to Get.Workspace:
https://0xevilc0de.com/excel-4-macros-get-workspace-reference/

Answer (score 2):

You can format your Excel date in `YYYY-MM-DD` date format using the following (assuming your date is in cell A1, and Excel functions are in English):

```
=YEAR(A1) & "-" & RIGHT("0"&MONTH(A1);2) & "-" & RIGHT("0"&DAY(A1);2)
```

The advantages:

- works independently of your current locale settings (e.g. works with Excel in English and swiss-french locale fr-CH)
- requires no macro

The disadvantages:

- it's not very readable

Comment: RE Disadvantaged not readable; In newer excel versions you could create a name in name manager referring to your own custom function. e.g. `DATETEXT` and set it to refer to `=LAMBDA(date, YEAR(date) & "-" & RIGHT("0"&MONTH(date), 2) & "-" & RIGHT("0"&DAY(date),2))`, called like `=DATETEXT(A1)`. Or even more readable perhaps `=LAMBDA(date,TEXTJOIN("-", TRUE, YEAR(date), TEXT(MONTH(date),"00"), TEXT(DAY(date),"00")))`

Answer (score 0):

Another option with no macros is to use `FORMULATEXT`:

In a random cell `Z5`

```swift
=TEXT(123, "foo")
```

Then in your desired cell `C1`

```swift
=TEXT(A1,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("TEKST", FORMULATEXT(Z5)), "YYYY", "RRRR") & "-MM-DD")
```

This works because the formula of the random cell will be updated to say TEKST in polish and you can just spot that happening. Obviously the other method is more robust to any country but this requires no settings to be changed.

---

Bigger:

```swift
=TEXT(
  A1,
  IF(
    ISERROR(
      SEARCH(
        "TEKST",
        FORMULATEXT(Z5)
      ),
      "YYYY",
      "RRRR"
    ) & "-MM-DD"
  )
```

Comment: This approach will only work if you have Excel in the same language as the operating system locale. In my case: Excel is in English (so the function is named `TEXT`), but my locale is FR-CH, so I need to use `aaaa-mm-jj` pattern ("année-mois-jour"="year-month-day").

Comment: @JulienKronegg Fair enough. Does the other answer work for you with the `GET.WORKSPACE`? I was answering the specific question on Poland and noted _"the other method is more robust to any country but this requires no [macro] settings to be changed"_ to try and clarify that this wouldn't work in the general case., but has the benefit of being a bit simpler.

Comment: I cannot use `GET.WORKSPACE` for security reasons, so I use https://stackoverflow.com/a/77006201/698168

Comment: @JulienKronegg I like that workaround. Funny thing is the semicolon `;` you use I have to swap with comma - but at least that is a one time change and will be performed automatically by Excel when you ship the workbook across the world once you have it working

Comment: Excel uses the system regional settings list separator, see https://www.officetooltips.com/office/tips/change_the_semicolon_to_a_comma_or_vice_versa.html (e.g. `;` in `fr-CH`, and `,` in `en-US`)

Answer (score -2):

The solution is actually simple, surprisingly so.

Whether specifying a formal Custom Format, or specifying a format inside a `TEXT()` (or `TEKST()` function), you just add the country-specific code for interpreting the formatting string. So, if a US-Excel version person is writing the formula, and is presumably most conversant in the US English strings to use, and especially if expecting the users to be US-Excel version users, he would write it as:

```
=TEXT(A1,"[$-en-US]YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Every version of Excel will then use the US English set of formatting string variables in interpreting the formatting string that follows the `[$-en-US]`. Since the string is perfectly valid in US English Excel, it will form the date properly and "textify" it as demanded. No error will be produced.

I cannot test a nuance here, that of whether Excel of a different language version will insert itself into the middle here and take the date as the string formats it, and map it to the particular language's names for months, but that is not asked for in the poster's question so... I have the feeling it will not and so one might need to do further work to make the Polish user happiest. If month names were used instead of month numbers.

But the key element of generating a correct numeric date display with no possibility — none at all — of an `#ERROR!` result rendering things ugly and useless will absolutely be accomplished with no great effort at all.

Comment: No, this answer is false. The "YYYY-MM-DD" part will still always be locale-dependent. The "[$-en-US]" part is there to revert any number-format back into English.