# Date-Formatting in TEXT formula independent from used language in Excel does not work anymore after update of Office365

Tags: excel, excel-formula

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65326720/date-formatting-in-text-formula-independent-from-used-language-in-excel) I have been using the below solution to have a date-format in a TEXT formula independent from the language that is used in Excel:

**Excel:**

```
  |       A      |       B        |
--|--------------|----------------|-
1 |  2021-11-01  |   #BLOCKED!    |
2 |              |                |
```

**Formula in B1:**

```
B1 = TEXT(A2,REPT(@Time_Global_Year,4)&"-"&REPT(@Time_Global_Month,2)&"-"&REPT(@Time_Global_Day,2))
```

**Name Manager:**

```
Time_Global_Year = INDEX(GET.WORKSPACE(37),19)
Time_Global_Month = INDEX(GET.WORKSPACE(37),20)
Time_Global_Day = INDEX(GET.WORKSPACE(37),21)
```

---

However, after Office365 version has been updated I am suddenly getting the error `#BLOCKED!` instead of a date in `Cell B1`.

Do you know what I need to change to make it work again?

Comment: Excel 4 Macros – Get.Workspace Reference https://malware.news/t/excel-4-macros-get-workspace-reference/38892

Comment: Excel 4.0 Macro Functions Reference: https://d13ot9o61jdzpp.cloudfront.net/files/Excel%204.0%20Macro%20Functions%20Reference.pdf

Comment: Working with Excel 4.0 macros: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/working-with-excel-4-0-macros-ba8924d4-e157-4bb2-8d76-2c07ff02e0b8

Comment: Comments about group policy: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/restrict-usage-of-excel-4-0-xlm-macros-with-new-macro-settings/ba-p/2528450

Comment: Apparently Excel 4.0 Macro Functions are viewed as a security threat. The option to enable them is not available in my Excel 2016 Trust Center settings. There may still be a way to enable them but I didn't see it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments enabling Excel 4.0 macros solved the problem:

[image]