# Weekday from date in TEXT formula independent from used language in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
            A         |       B       |
----------------------|---------------|--------------------------                    
1      2022-02-14     |       Mo      |    B1 = TEXT(A1,"DDD")
2                     |               |
3                     |               |
```

I have a date written in `Cell A1` and I want to extract the weekday from it in `Cell B1`. 
All this works fine as long as I use the English version of Excel.

---

Now, some co-workers use the German version of Excel. 
When they open the file the `DDD` part of the formula is not recognized anymore. 
Therefore, instead of the weekday in `Cell B2` just `DDD` as text is displayed. 
I think this problem is quite similar to the issue in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65326720/date-formatting-in-text-formula-independent-from-used-language-in-excel).

---

Therefore, I already implemented the following formula to the name manager:

```
Time_Global_Day =INDEX(GET.WORKSPACE(37),21)
```

Afterwards I switched the formula in `Cell B1` to:

```
=TEXT(A1,REPT(@Time_Global_Day,2))
```

With this solution I am able to extract the day as number from the date in `Cell A1`.

How do I need to modify it to display the **weekday** no **matter which language** is used for Excel?

Comment: We did this by first getting the lical language settings then using choise to pick any one of 5 languages from a table containg the seven days for each language.

Comment: So what would be your preferred output? The written words `Monday` etc...?

Comment: @JvdV: Yes, either Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday ... or the short version of them Mo, Tu, We, ...

Comment: So have you considered `=TEXT(A1,REPT(Time_Global_Day,4))`? It kind of literally is answered in the linked question you had previously.

Comment: Perhaps I am not catching the problem, but couldn't you put this `=INDEX({"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"},WEEKDAY(A1))` in B1?

Comment: @markfitzpatrick, that won't be locale dependent. In Dutch you'd want 'Zon', 'Mon', 'Din', 'Woe', etc. for example.

Comment: @JvdV - ah OK - then I misunderstood the objective. I thought it was to force the result into EN.

Comment: @JvdV: Thanks for the answer. It works. I am wondering if there is also solution that always displays the names in English no matter which language is setup in Excel.

Comment: @Michi, cool. Glad it's solved. Btw, to always appear as english: `=TEXT(A2,"[$-409]"&REPT(Time_Global_Day,4))`. For now I've closed your question as it's literally just a change of numers in the repetition as one would do in normal number-formatting. Let me know if you agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from JvdV in the comments solves the problem:

```
full name of days   -->  B1 = TEXT(A1,REPT(Time_Global_Day,4))
short name of days  -->  B1 = TEXT(A1,REPT(Time_Global_Day,3))
```

If the names should be always in English you need to add `"[$-409]"` in front of `REPT`:

```
full name of days   -->  B1 = TEXT(A1,"[$-409]"&REPT(Time_Global_Day,4))
short name of days  -->  B1 = TEXT(A1,"[$-409]"&REPT(Time_Global_Day,3))
```

---

**NOTE:** Depending on which version of Excel you use it could be necessary to: 
`Enable Excel 4.0 macros when VBA macros are enabled` in the `Trust Center`.

Comment: True. Fixed it.