# How to know which regional settings Excel uses in =TEXT() formula for formatting dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a lot of code that breaks down completely depending on the machine I use it on if the date formatting in a =TEXT() function does not work as it was supposed to.

I have 2 computers at at home with the same version of Excel- a desktop and a laptop, both with English subscription versions of Excel. It works on desktop, but not on laptop, apparently different regional settings. Then again it works on a German machine with German regional settings - where it is supposed to work.

What I assumed was, that using yyyymmdd would produce 20221125 for today regardless of a machine. Turns out it is not so, as seen in the picture. Super irritating.

In order to mitigate that I now check the result of a

```
=TEXT(A1,"yyyymmdd")

=TEXT(A1,"jjjjMMTT")
```

and so on where A1 is a known date and I now that result of that field should be 20000101 for example.
The other alternative that also worked is to look for letters from "yyyymmdd" in a result of the TEXT formula.

Once I found the correct string I can use it further to format all dates.

It is doable, but super irritating.

[image]

Is there a way to know the regional settings without jumping through hoops?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try including a language code in the format, eg. `=TEXT(A1,"[$-809]yyyymmdd")` [See here](https://excel.tips.net/T003299_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html)

Comment: Nope. That does not work. It doesn't throw an error with the right country codes, it throws #VALUE error with wrong country codes but the result stays the same. In the meantime I found similar ideas to mine with slightly different implementations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65326720/date-formatting-in-text-formula-independent-from-used-language-in-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the date string, use a defined name:

```
eg:  =Text(N11, dtFormat)
```

Enter this Auto-Open event code in the Workbook module:

```
Option Explicit
'change text function date code
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim yrCode As String, mnthCode As String, dyCode As String
    Dim dtCode As String
    Dim nM As Name
    
With Application
    yrCode = WorksheetFunction.Rept(.International(xlYearCode), 4)
    mnthCode = WorksheetFunction.Rept(.International(xlMonthCode), 2)
    dyCode = WorksheetFunction.Rept(.International(xlDayCode), 2)
End With

'Can only add a name if it is absent
For Each nM In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If nM.Name = "dtFormat" Then
        nM.Delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next nM

dtCode = yrCode & mnthCode & dyCode
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add _
 Name:="dtFormat", _
 RefersTo:="=""" & dtCode & """", _
 Visible:=False

End Sub
```

The code determines the proper format characters, and ensures that `dtFormat` is properly defined based on the machine on which the workbook is opened.

Comment: Thanks it works. It is "more international" than my solution with formulas that check for presence of letters in formatted dates. My solution catches only yyyymmdd or jjjjMMTT. If  I brought my workbook to some other language setting it would fail with other names for year, month or date.

Answer (score 1):

This formula (no VBA) should give you the expected result, does not matter what are the regional settings:

```
=TEXT(YEAR(A1),"0000")&TEXT(MONTH(A1),"00")&TEXT(DAY(A1),"00")
```

Comment: Good. Works, but not with weekday names and moth names.

Answer (score 0):

With an UDF you can do it like this:
[image]

```
Public Function GetFormat$(Cell As Range, Optional ByVal UseLocal As Boolean)
    'get the date region settings of this computer
'    https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul
'    =GetFormat($A$1, TRUE)
    
    If UseLocal Then
        GetFormat = Cell.NumberFormatLocal
    Else
        GetFormat = Cell.NumberFormat
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a VBA User defined Funktion (UDF) like this:

[image]

```
Public Function FMT$(ByVal Value, ByVal strFormat)
    'used instead of the Text Function in Excel (Formula) to provide a date format which is region specific
    'https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul
    FMT = VBA.Format$(Value, strFormat)
End Function
```