# Excel TEXT function for date in a bilingual environment

Tags: excel, date-formatting

I work in a bilingual environment, English and Frensh, and I made a tool that need to be use by multiple user.
In a cell I am creating a concatenate string whit the curent date in it. (="Date: "&TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm dd, yyyy")
Now when the French user open the tool, they get an error because they French version of EXCEL doesn't reconise "mmmm dd, yyyy" if I change it to "mmmm jj, aaaa" which is the french equivalent it solve the problem.
Any idea how to make this formula working in both language?

Thank you

Comment: try: `="Date: "&IFERROR(TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm dd, yyyy"),TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm jj, aaaa"))` I have no way to test it, so I do not know if it will work or not.

Comment: If you can use VBA, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64854470/date-format-excel-in-diferent-systems-german-to-english) for how to use the TEXT function with different languages.  It uses the `Workbook_Open` to setup (or modify) a Named formula which is the date format string.  That "Name" is then used in your TEXT function and will have the proper codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
="Date: "&TEXT(TODAY(),IF(TEXT(TODAY(),"y")="y","mmmm jj, aaaa","mmmm dd, yyyy"))
```

There is probably a way to cover all the languages. Since we need only french and english, this should be enouth already.

As suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/786790/text-function-in-excel-isnt-formatting-year) you can also use something like this:

```
="Date: "&TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm")&" "&DAY(TODAY())&", "&YEAR(TODAY())
```

Comment: In such case, consider marking the answer as accepted.