# Problem with excel recognizing dates to create text

Tags: excel, string, date, excel-formula

Currently, I am truly stumped as to what could be wrong.

The problem:
I have a cell in excel formatted as a date (e.g., `19/10/2023`). I would like to take that cell and format it as a text in another cell via the formula `=TEXT(C4; "dd.mm.yyyy")`, where `C4` is the cell containing that date `19/10/2023`. Unfortunately, the output from `=TEXT(C4; "dd.mm.yyyy")` is `dd.00.yyyy`.

Can anyone help me in this regard? Is it an issue with my settings?

Otherwise, I have tried functions like `=TODAY()` and `=MONTH(C4)` that seem to work fine. In addition, I have tried `=TEXT(C4; "dd/mm/yyyy")` which yields the same problem as `=TEXT(C4; "dd.mm.yyyy")`

Comment: Right-click a cell with a 'date' and select `Format Cells`. Select the `Number` tab (if not already selected) and if the selection in the list box is `Date`, select `Custom` instead. That should show you which characters are used for dates in your Excel. If the selection in the list box isn't `Date`, then the cell doesn't contain a date. Please share what you have discovered.

Comment: Currently, the selection is `Date`. When I click on `Custom`, I get TT/MM/JJJJ selected as the as the format. Note TT/MM/JJJJ is the German date version I believe

Comment: There you have it: `=TEXT(C4;"TT.MM.JJJJ")`. **T**ag, **M**onat, **J**ahr (**D**ay, **M**onth, **Y**ear). Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Ah awesome, thanks - it works. Quick question: The format snippet for the formula needs to remain as "DD.MM.YYYY" so that others can also use it. What do I need to do on my excel?

Comment: Don't use the formula version, but custom formatting if you can't ti keep the date a date. TEXT turns it into actual text.

Comment: If you need to have the date as **text**, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64854470/date-format-excel-in-diferent-systems-german-to-english) for a method to alter the format text string within the `TEXT` function depending on the users regional settings.